# Android what does this columns from content provider suggests?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

what does `new` and `is_read` suggests in the call logs we got from content provider I was not able to understand the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html#IS_READ).

It seems both are same.

and my data is `type:3` that is `missed call type` and it has `is_read is 1` and for others `is_read is null`. and my `new` is always `null`

Note `type ,new` and `is_read` are columns from call log.
All this data is from Moto devices.

- Image details are from other device(do not know) and looks like it has some new columns in which some columns are not in Android docs also.
     [image: xml of columns]
- Does this fields and their values changes based on
  Manufacturer(SAMSUNG MI) or is it based on API Level or OS.
- It would be helpful if i get any reference.